# How to create background for LinearLayout as shown in the image below

Tags: android

How to create background for LinearLayout as shown in the image below. I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to put a picture such as a background.

Comment: Specify your reason for giving -ive vote....

Comment: I want to draw it somehow pragramatically and don't want to use a picture.... @MikiFranko

Comment: If so, you have to use the canvas and you can draw as you wish.

Comment: @MikiFranko Above image also have shadow at the top edge, so how i can draw it on canvas. Any help ?????

Comment: You'd best be using a **9 patch**.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Relative Layout to add View above another View. For Above Mention Image you just need two images And you have to create your layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To Add Dynamic View you can create overlay bitmap as:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        Bitmap bitmapCopy1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas1 = new Canvas(bitmapCopy1); 
        Bitmap pinImage = Utility.createBitmap(pinFloor);
        canvas1.drawBitmap(pinImage, leftPos[i], topPos[i], new Paint());    
        firstImage.setImageBitmap(firstBitmap);
        firstImage.setImageBitmap(bitmapCopy1);
        firstImage.invalidate();
```

Comment: But according to my requirement i have to draw it programatically somehow without using image......

Comment: @user3074539 Extend `View` and override method `onDraw()`. You can draw there anything you like (programatically).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RelativeLayout` with a background of the yellow color and add the circle image on top.

This is a far more dynamic solution than using a single image as the `RelativeLayout` will change size depending on screen size/orientation and not affect the sizing of the circle

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffc20e">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```